# Simplifying $a(a-2) = b(b+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I reduced a number theory problem to finding all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ that satisfy the equation $a(a-2) = b(b+2)$ in a certain range. After thinking about this for a while, I figured that either $a = b + 2$, $a = -b$, $a = b = 0$ or $a = 2 \text{ and } b = -2$. It is easy to prove that these values for $a$ and $b$ will all satisfy the equation, but how would I solve this equation had I not come up with these solutions? And how do I know I did not miss one? *In short, can this equation be solved (more) rigorously?*

*Edit*:
Silly of me I did not recognize that my last two solutions were already covered by my first two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add $1$ to both sides to get
$$a^2 - 2a + 1 = b^2 + 2b + 1$$
i.e.
$$(a-1)^2 = (b+1)^2.$$

Hence $a-1 = b+1$ or $a-1 = -b-1$ and these are all solutions.

Comment: I'd simplify the last expressions to $a=b+2$ or $a=-b$ just to be nice.

Comment: @JBKing Sure, but the OP seemed to have that already.

Answer (score 5):

Denote $c=b+2$. Then 
$(a-1)^2=(c-1)^2$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

$a(a - 2) = b(b + 2)$

$a^2 - 2a = b^2 + 2b$

$a^2 - b^2 = 2(b + a)$

$(a + b)(a - b) = 2(a + b)$

$(a + b)(a - b - 2) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to note that $a=b+2$ is an "obvious" solution, then to divide by that solution:
$$
\frac{a(a-2)-b(b+2)}{a-(b+2)}=a+b
$$
giving $a(a-2)-b(b+2)=(a-(b+2))(a+b)$. Therefore, the solutions are
$$
a=b+2\quad\text{and}\quad a=-b
$$

Comment: You divided by 0 when you divided by a-b+2, is there a reason why you didn't get an erroneous result from this?

Comment: When looking for *another* solution, $a-(b+2)\ne0$, so it *is* legal.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\, b=x.\, f(x) = x^2\!+\!\color{#c00}2x = a^2\!-\!2a= f(-a)$ has roots $x=-a,\ x'\!=a\!-\!2,$ by $\, x\!+\!x'\!=-\color{#c00}2.$